Помогите доделать консольного динозаврика на C#
Ума не приложу как сделать движущиеся кактусы и самого динозаврика.
Заранее спасибо
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Threading;

namespace DINO
{
    class DINO
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            while (true)
            {
                generation();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.Clear();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static void generation()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            /*    OBJECTS FOR GAME, WORLD LENGTH AND WIDTH    */
            int WorldLength = 10;
            int WorldWidth = 50;
            string cloud2 = "о";
            string cloud = "О";
            string cactus = "8";
            string dirt = "-";

            /*    WORLD    */
            string[,] world = new string[WorldLength, WorldWidth];

            /*    WORLD GENERATION    */
            for (int i = 0; i < WorldLength; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < WorldWidth; j++)
                {
                    /*    FLOOR    */
                    if (i == 9)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = dirt;
                    }

                    /*    CLOUD1   */
                    else if (i == 2 & j == 3)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = cloud;
                    }
                    else if (i == 2 & j == 2)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = cloud2;
                    }
                    else if (i == 2 & j == 4)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = cloud2;
                    }

                    /*    CLOUD2   */
                    else if (i == 2 & j == 15)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = cloud;
                    }
                    else if (i == 2 & j == 14)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = cloud2;
                    }
                    else if (i == 2 & j == 16)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = cloud2;
                    }

                    /*    CLOUD3   */
                    else if (i == 2 & j == 28)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = cloud;
                    }
                    else if (i == 2 & j == 27)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = cloud2;
                    }
                    else if (i == 2 & j == 29)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = cloud2;
                    }

                    /*    CLOUD4   */
                    else if (i == 2 & j == 45)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = cloud;
                    }
                    else if (i == 2 & j == 44)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = cloud2;
                    }
                    else if (i == 2 & j == 46)
                    {
                        world[i, j] = cloud2;
                    }

                    /*    CACTUS GENERATION    */



                    /*    SKY    */
                    else
                    {
                        world[i, j] = " ";
                    }

                    if (j == WorldWidth - 1) Console.WriteLine(world[i, j]);
                    else Console.Write(world[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}






С чем именно возникли трудности?

Такой совет - откройте для себя switch и pattern matching, чтобы избавиться от этих простыней с if-ами
